# Applying a force of $c$ newtons to a $1\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$ object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, forces, speed-of-light

My understanding is that forces in matter cannot propagate faster than the speed of light. If there were a  hypothetical rod going from the surface of the earth to the moon, it would take $1.28\ \mathrm{ms}$ for a tug on the rod from Earth to be felt on the moon, which I got by calculating

$$\frac{\text{distance to moon}}{\text{speed of light}}.$$

So, if a $299\,792\,458\ \mathrm N$ force were applied to a solid inelastic cube at rest (in respect to the universe) with a mass of $1\ \mathrm{kg}$ and a size of $1\ \mathrm m$ by $1\ \mathrm m$ by $1\ \mathrm m$ in a $1\ \mathrm m$ by $1\ \mathrm m$ inelastic chute (to prevent a side-ways explosion), would the side of the cube facing the force accelerate so fast that the cube is pressed into 2d flatland, or what would happen? Is there a real example that demonstrates the effect?

Comment: FYI I believe it would travel at the speed of sound in the material, not the speed of light.

Comment: 1.28 ms? c is 1 million feet per millisecond.

Comment: “$c$ newtons” doesn’t make any sense; $c$ is a speed. It is 299792458 meters per second, not the number 299792458. The numerical value can be any positive number you want, by picking the right units.

Comment: @downvoter Why the downvote? I thought that the purpose of this forum was learning and education. We ask our silly and sometimes dumb questions here and learn from our mistakes so that we are not as dumb in our daily lives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to accelerate anything (with mass, although this is implied as anything without mass can only travel at the speed of light) to the speed of light. Period. In your rod example the "tug" would travel along the rod at the speed of sound in whatever material it is made of, not the speed of light.

Comment: Could you post a link that explains this in more detail? I am confused about how something accelerated faster than the speed of sound per second squared would not be squashed? For example, lets say you pushed the hypothetical rod up by 5m. Would that 5m simply disappear and ripple upwards along the pole at the speed of sound until it reached the moon? After you provide a link, I'll check mark your answer. Call it blackmail 

Comment: Are you possibly confusing the speed of sound and speed of light here? In your original question your calculation implies that you are expecting the "squash" of the rod to travel at the speed of light.

Comment: I do not know. I know that a sound wave would travel along the pole at a certain speed, but I am asking more about a push and a shove. Because change is not propagated instantaneously, even an inelastic object must be slightly shorter when accelerated than when at rest. What is the speed of this propagation? Thank you.

Comment: The speed of light is the speed at which [photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon) travel in a vacuum, it is the absolute speed limit of the universe, nothing can travel faster than it. The speed of sound varies, depending on what material the sound wave is travelling in. When you push one end of the rod it pushes the next part of the rod and so on, travelling as a wave down the rod until it reaches the other end. The speed of this propagation is the speed of sound in whatever material the rod is made of.

Comment: When you say "inelastic object" are you referring to some kind of object that is absolutely solid and incompressible? Because a material like that does not/can't exist.

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question. I was referring to an inelastic object to simplify things. Thank you.